# How to transcode Unicode to ISO 8859-1 with postgres 13

Tags: postgresql, unicode, postgresql-13

How can I transcode a UTF-8 string to Latin1 with PostgreSQL 13+ ?

I've read [this SO thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81356/postgresql-and-utf8-to-latin1-conversion) but the functions `convert()`, `convert_from()` and `convert_to()` [no longer exist](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-string.html) starting from Postgres 13.

EDIT: the solution is given by Laurenz Albe, who pointed out that the functions still exist. I was only afterwards that I noticed:

- Google made me land on [the manual for 8.2](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/functions-string.html), for which convert() has a different signature than in version 8.3+
- I tried the 8.2 SQL code that resulted in `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "USING"`
- I couldn't find the function in the version 13 docs, because:
- the function manual has been moved to [Binary functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-binarystring.html)

So the correct SQL should have been:

```
SELECT convert('text_in_utf8', 'UTF8', 'LATIN1');
```

Comment: UTF to LATIN1 is done automatically. Could you show us a real problem you're facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`convert_from` and `convert_to` still exist, but they cannot convert from `text` to `text` because `text` is always a string in the database encoding.  Strings in other encoding can only be stored as `bytea`.

I cannot guide you any further, because you didn't tell us what problem you are trying to solve.